# Getting list of files from xap, to be stored in isolated stoarge on application launch

Tags: .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am creating a application in which big list of assets (files and image, file count more than 100) used by application.

This assets can be modified during the running time of the program.
Hence, I am planning to copy these files into Isolated Storage. To do so I've to have list of all the file names available in some file.

The file count later. Is there any way, to get the list of content files programmatically? SO that I can recursively copy this file in from XAP to isolated storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to query the contents of the xap file once installed on a device.

However, at build time you can easily generate such a list (with T4, PowerShell, a CMD/BAT script, or a simple console app) and have it output the list in such a format you can easily use in your code.

The advantage of doing this is that your app will be that bit faster as it doesn't need to generate the file list on every device, you just do it once, on your dev/build machine.